# Call function when chart y-value exceeds line's y-value

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have a candlestick chart which automatically updates with real time prices from a cryptocurrency exchange in the .NET forms. The goal is to make the bot preform actions when the price on chart passes one of the lines drawn by the user. So far I've come to the point of enabling line-drawing for users thanks to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e90055f-0c8f-431b-89a9-dd4a0ed43454/drawing-line-on-candlestick-chart?forum=MSWinWebChart).

Could anyone please point me towards a method of detecting collision between the chart candles and the drawn lines? I feel like there must be an easier way than what I'm thinking of currently, just can't seem to figure out the way to it.

Using the exact solution for the line drawing as in the article, also posted code for the line-drawing below:

```
int index1 = 1;
int index2 = 4;

DataPoint left = chart.Series[0].Points[index1];
DataPoint right = chart.Series[0].Points[index2];

    //Init the annotation
    LineAnnotation line = new LineAnnotation();
    line.AxisX = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    line.AxisY = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    line.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;

    //Each point in a candlestick series has several y values, 0=high, 1=low, 2=open, 3=close
    line.Y = left.YValues[1]; //low
    line.X = left.XValue;
    //If your data is indexed (your x values are Strings or you've set Series.IsXValueIndexed to true), use the data point index(+1) as the line X coordinate.
    //line.X = index1 + 1;

    //Use the width and height properties to determine the end position of the annotation.
    line.Height = right.YValues[1] - left.YValues[1];
    line.Width = right.XValue - left.XValue;
    //Again, use the index if necessary
    //line.Width = index2 - index1;

    chart.Annotations.Add(line);
```

**Just looking for a point in the direction of an easier solution, not the solution itself :) Thanks in advance!**

Comment: The *detecting collision between the chart candles and the drawn lines* seems like a really hard way to do this.  I assume that when they draw the line you can estimate what the line value is (say $5,000).  It not that hard to check when your graph updates if any of the values exceeds the lines value..

Comment: @ErikPhilips If the line is horizontal it's not an issue at all :) The problems start if there are several lines, and some have angles on them, let's say 20* degrees counter-clockwise :)

Comment: That also simple [90 Degree Triangle - Trigonometry](https://revisionmaths.com/gcse-maths-revision/trigonometry/sin-cos-and-tan).

Comment: Do you want to just know it passed or where it passed or by how much at any given point?

Comment: Imagine a marketing chart. If the price exceeds a certain amount, or drops below a certain about, you buy or sell an amount of the currency. The user is supposed to be able to draw lines on the chart, and the program is supposed to buy or sell when the chart (price) crosses those lines.

Comment: As Erik wrote: this is really just very basic math: You have two points on the line, so you also have the slope. With one of the points and your new x-value you can calculate the y-value of the line and compare with your new datapoint-y.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you are asking is if a [Point (Geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(geometry)) is above or below a line.

Here are the assumption (which you can change later to fit your needs):

1. an external resource is giving you a specific value (Y) at a specific point in time (X), which will call the *Integral point XY*.
2. The user has drawn a line which gives you a starting point (x1, y1) and an end point (x2, y2).
3. The graphs X component is in minutes, with each tick horizontally is 1 minute.
4. The graphs Y component is in dollars, with each tick is $25.
5. The user has drawn a line from (1:00pm, $50) to (1:05pm, $75).
6. We get an *Integral Point XY* at 1:10pm of $125.

What is the value of the line at 1:10pm so you can compare it to the *Integral Point XY*.

Based on my comments of [Trigonometry](https://revisionmaths.com/gcse-maths-revision/trigonometry/sin-cos-and-tan)..

[image]

- We know the adjacent length is: 1:05 - 1:00 = 5
- We know the opposite length is: 75 - 25 = 50
- Using the formula: atan(opposite / adjacent) = angle

  - We calculate that the angle is: atan(50 / 5) = 1.47112767rad (radians)

Now we simply reverse our math:

- We know the adjacent length is: 1:10 - 1:00 = 10
- We know our Angle in Radians: 1.47112767
- Using the formula: adjacent * tan(angle) = opposite

  - We calculate that the opposite is: 10 * tan(1.47112767) = ~$99.999999 or $100

$125 is above $100, do what you want.